# On notation used in Pollard's book regarding convergence of a generalized-M estimator

Tags: probability, estimation, econometrics, stochastic-processes

I am following the famous book by Pollard *Convergence of stochastic processes* (1984) and he writes

[image]

I don't understand how is the deterministic function $H(\theta)$ defined, in particular what is that P he puts at the start of it? Is it a probability measure? over what set?

Comment: pollard uses $\mathbb{P}$ to denote the expectation with respect to $\mathbb{P}$. It seems like he's taking the joint expectation with respect to $y_1$ and $u_1$.

Comment: @user795305 Thank you! could you expand a bit on why we would hope that the $\theta_n$ converge to the $\theta^*$? why are we only looking at the first two random variables $y_1$ and $y_2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a population function $H(\theta)$ of the parameter that has a root at the true parameter $\theta^*$. $H(\theta)$ is given by the moment condition $E[g(y_t)\epsilon_t] = 0$.
Under the assumption, $(y_t)$ is strictly stationary. So $E[g(y_t)\epsilon_t]$ is independent of $t$; $t=1$ is used in the formulation you quote above.

As is the case for M-estimators, under appropriate assumptions (mixing of suitable size, stochastic equicontinuity,etc), the sample counterpart $(H_n(\cdot))$ converges uniformly in probability to $H$. So if the root of $H$ is, for example, unique, then the root of $H_n(\cdot)$ converges in probability to $\theta^*$.